# Dynamically create Excel file daily with SQL data in Power automate

Tags: azure, power-automate

I have created a power automate flow to execute a sql query and create a sharepoint file in excel format everyday and load the retrieved select query to the excel file. PFB the attached picture on how to pass the file name dynamically like today's date in the file name (create file task).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this ...

```
concat('Prefix_', formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(utcNow(), 'AUS Eastern Standard Time'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), '.txt')
```

... I'm not creating an Excel file, just a text file and I'm doing it for my own timezone.  This is the result in SharePoint ...

[image: Create File]

[image: Result]