# Load select query into excel file using power automate

Tags: azure, power-automate

I have created a power automate flow to execute a sql query and create a sharepoint file in excel format everyday and load the retrieved select query to the excel file. Can anyone suggest what to provide in file content in the below screenshot and also how to load data into excel file in sharepoint?

[image]

Comment: I wondered if you’d run into this issue hence why on the answer I gave to your other question, I used a text file. I have a solution for you but can’t answer right now, will do so as soon as I can though.

Comment: These are the steps to be followed: create sharepoint file(excel), create excel table, inside apply each(add row into table). In this method, I get issue while creating excel table saying badgateway with 8 retires.

Comment: Oh ok, the workbook is able to be created and updated with a table but that’s it? So you can confirm the table exists in the workbook by opening it and checking?

Comment: I am able to create excel file but getting error while creating excel table in the excel

Comment: You can't just create an Excel file by using the create file action, it's just a blank nothing file, it has no XML structure to it which indicates that it's an Excel spreadsheet.  I have a solution for you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, create a template Excel file in the SharePoint folder your flow will have access to (called `Template.xlsx` below) ...

[image: Template Workbook]

Now in your flow, copy that workbook to another workbook in another folder, I've done that to the `Completed` folder.  Technically, you could put it anywhere though ...

[image: Copy File]

... now in the next step, rename your file by calling one of the API's on the SharePoint site in question ...

[image: Rename File]

You need to make sure you enter the following headers and then body (be sure to parameterise your filename though) ...

**Uri:** `_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items(@{outputs('Copy_file')?['body/ItemId']})`

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| X-HTTP-Method | MERGE |
| If-Match | * |
| Content-Type | application/json;odata=verbose |

**Body**

```
{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.Data.Shared_x0020_DocumentsItem"
  },
  "FileLeafRef": "New File Name.xlsx"
}
```

Now you have a true Excel workbook to work with.

[image: Renamed File]

Comment: Great. This helps. In my flow, the steps are Execute the query (SQL), Create sharepoint excel file with todays date as filename. Is there a way to load the sql result into excel file using http request? And also in this send HTTP request where are we inserting the query results into excel? This is in sequence with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71962419/dynamically-create-excel-file-daily-with-sql-data-in-power-automate/71962696#71962696

Comment: Yeah, but it’s kinda secondary to this question so technically, you should flag this question as answered and then open another question. Having said that, you should have a crack with the **Create table** action that you were previously using. I think you were on the right track, you just needed to overcome this question.